# For this torture, you'll pay

Tags: riddle

> Upside down, but not falling
>   In terror, you'll be calling
>   With fear, and dismay
>   For this torture, you'll pay
>
> And when it's all over
>   You'll walk away, shaken
>   But amused - no regrets
>   For this path that you've taken

Explain what this is describing.

Comment: 'dismay' is a bit of a stretch for me, but otherwise a great riddle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> a Roller Coaster ?

Upside down, but not falling

> you don't fall because of protections

In terror, you'll be calling

> People are shouting

With fear, and dismay
For this torture, you'll pay

> You have to pay for the roller coaster

And when it's all over
You'll walk away, shaken
But amused - no regrets
For this path that you've taken

> You were afraid but you liked it, it's an amusement ride

Answer (score 7):

It's a:

> Rollercoaster

Upside down, but not falling

> Rollercoasters can go upside down but you're locked in and can't fall.

In terror, you'll be calling

> People often scream...

With fear, and dismay

> ... because they're terrified with excitement and dizzy.

For this torture, you'll pay

> Cost to ride one.

And when it's all over

> They ride comes to and end...

You'll walk away, shaken

> ... and you get out and wobble away buzzing for the excitement.

But amused - no regrets

> It's all in good fun - you wanted to and chose to go on it.

For this path that you've taken

> Rollercoasters follow a track that's its path.

Comment: Nice work! A well-written solution, but accepting the first one per Puzzling convention.